# Moment-generating function of the log-normal distribution. A question about integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

Consider the probability density function $f(x)$ of the log-normal distribution with parameters $-0.1$ and $0.01$:

```
f[x_] = PDF[LogNormalDistribution[-0.1, 0.01], x];
```

It is well-known that the moment-generating function of the log-normal distribution, $m(t)=\int_0^\infty e^{tx}f(x)\,dx$, is not defined for $t>0$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)). However, for $t=1$, both

```
NIntegrate[Exp[x]*f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

and

```
NExpectation[Exp[X], X \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[-0.1, 0.01]]
```

give $2.47174$ as a result. What is happening here?

Comment: moment-generating function is the expectation of $Exp[t*x]$,but here what you calculate is the expectation of $Exp[x]$

Comment: @Xminer Yes, I'm computing the moment-generating function $m(t)$ at $t=1$.

Comment: `Integrate[ Exp[x] PDF[LogNormalDistribution[-1/10, 1/100], x], {x, 0, Infinity}]` doesn't seem to detect the divergence of the integral and just leaves it unevaluated. I'm guessing that `NIntegrate` doesn't either and just gives it a try. The integrant goes to zero fast enough that the divergence remains undetected by numerical methods.

Comment: `NIntegrate` produces a result without messages indicating divergence because of a combination of factors -- variable change, singularity handling, and integrand's nature. (Sjoert is right.) I will try to post an answer later today.

Comment: The moment generating function for the log normal distribution is mentioned in the *Possible Issues* section of the documentation for `MomentGeneratingFunction`.